# Order of an element in a cyclic group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Without using Lagrange's Theorem or permutations, why must the order of an element in a cyclic group divide the order of the group?

I think it has something to do with the fact that every element in a cyclic group can be written as a form of the generator.

Comment: Use the good ol divison algorithm for integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $z \in G$ be a generator of the cyclic group $G$ of order $n$. Let $x \in G$ be arbitrary, i.e. $x = z^k$ for some $0 < k < n$ and let $l = ord(x)$. You want $l | n$. So by **euclidean division** we can write $n = pl + q$ for $p,q$ integers and $0 \leq q < l$. Clearly we have $e = x^n = x^{pl+q} = x^{pl} x^q$. You have to show that $q = 0$, can you do it?

Comment: Not really, I don't know what to do with that equation. Also what does p stand for?

Comment: @Maria ... see the edit. Is it now clearer?

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much